# Find Contour Such that Only One Intersection Exists

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I'm trying to work out a visualization in Desmos, but I'm having trouble finding a closed form solution.

The problem is that I have a function

1. $$(|x|^k + |y|^k)^\frac{1}{k} = 5$$

that I would like to intersect only once with the following ellipse

2. $$\frac{((x - 10)\cos(-1) + (y - 10)\sin(-1))^2}{a} + \frac{((x - 10)\cos(-1) - (y - 10)\sin(-1))^2}{b} = c.$$

How can find or set $c$ as a function of $k$ such that there is only one intersection?

Comment: @Mason Equation (1) is just trying to model the Minowoski distances, so in some circumstances $k$ can take non-integer values from [0, inf]. The -1 is in fact radians. Equation (2) is just a general form for eclipse with -1 adding a skew / tilt/

Comment: Sorry, ellipse is the correct term.

Comment: @Mason Here's what I'm trying to work on: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ohx8vtyipl. However, the green ellipse is current not a function of $k$. Ideally, when $k$ shifts, both the blue and green will intersect at only one point.

Comment: $a, b$ are both fixed so that we can find $c$ as a function of $k$

Comment: Fixed but arbitrary? I mean: they are fixed at what value?

Comment: For now, fix $a = 40$ and $b \approx 95.78$. The point is that it doesn't matter what values those are. I suppose a general solution for $c$ as a function of $k, a, b$ will be easier to find.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: If you are interested in a class of solutions when $k\leq1$: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/trnctaljoj. $a \approx 52.1145632603$ and $b \approx 324.903791308$

Comment: I kind of need a solution that generalizes to values of $k$ between [0, inf].

Comment: The first equation can be written as $y = \pm e^{\left( \ln(5^k - \lvert x \rvert^k) \right) / k} = \pm \left( 5^k - \lvert x \rvert^k \right)^{1/k}$. Are you looking for (efficient ways of finding) a numerical solution (for $c$ such that there is exactly one intersection between the two disks), or algebraic approaches only?

Comment: I would prefer an algebraic approach for finding a $c$ such that there is exactly one intersection, as I'm trying to create an interactive plot with the result.